# JSS Workflow - How to default newly create items to Content Mode?

Tags: jss, workflow

*Sitecore 10.1, JSS 16*

I am using a user with the sitecore/Author role that I have added access to "write" when items are in the "Content Mode" state. However when I create a new App Route, it defaults to "Development Mode" and the user does not have permission to "write" for it.

**How to I default new items to be in "Content Mode"?**

Answer (score 1):

Found it under:
sitecore > System > Workflows > JSS Development Workflow

In the *Content* tab under *Data* there is a field "Initial state" which I changed to Content Mode!